# how to connect more than one client from one server

Tags: php, sockets

how to connect more than one client to a single server ,,  for a simple chat application between 2 clients.
I didn't get a proper answer on net,
should i have to create multiple sockets or ports ,
any reference or example code or guidance..
here is my server code

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 25003;

// No Timeout 
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
//echo $socket;
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");

$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
$output = strrev($input);    

socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n"); 
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple connections queued on the socket, the first will be used. If there are no pending connections, `socket_accept()` will block until a connection becomes present.
If you want to have multiple clients on a server you will have to use non blocking.

```
socket_set_nonblock($socket);
```